# How read .conf files from NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, configuration

Good time, there was a need to read the .conf file to pull out the values from there in saw VARIABLE = 'value', how can this be implemented?
The file itself also contains comments that I would like to ignore and find only the necessary values.

I tried to read the file linearly and knowing the line variables, read it

Comment: Can you send sample of the file?

Comment: #ACCEPTABLE VALUES mysql2 mariadb sqlite3 tedious oracledb
SQL_DB_DIALECT = 'postgres'

#THE IP ADDRESS WHERE YOUR DATABASE IS LOCATED, IF ON THE LOCAL COMPUTER WHERE THE DATABASE IS INSTALLED, USE 127.0.0.1
SQL_DB_IP = '192.168.11.128'

SQL_DB_PORT = '5432'

SQL_DB_DATABASE = 'quxide'

SQL_DB_USERNAME = 'quxide'

SQL_DB_PASSWORD = '277353'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you may be looking for.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
// read and store content of the config file
const envContent = fs.readFileSync('.conf', 'utf8');
// create an object to store the key-value pairs in the config file
const obj = {}

// iterate through each line of the config file
for (const line of envContent.split('\n')) {
  // check if line contain value and it is not a comment
  if (line && !line.startsWith('#')) {
    // get the key and value on the current line
    let [ key, val ] = line.split('=');
    // remove unneccessary spaces
    key = key.trim()
    // remove unneccessary spaces and quotes
    val = val.trim().replaceAll('"', '').replaceAll("'", "");
    // store it in the object created
    obj[key] = val;
  }
}

console.log(obj)
```

**Output**

```
{
  SQL_DB_DIALECT: 'postgres',
  SQL_DB_IP: '192.168.x.x',
  SQL_DB_PORT: '5432',
  SQL_DB_DATABASE: 'quxxxx',
  SQL_DB_USERNAME: 'quxxxx',
  SQL_DB_PASSWORD: '27xxx'
}
```